# Login failed for farm account when creating a SP2019 farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

I have a farm it has 2 application servers, 2 Web front end servers, 2 distributed cache servers, 2 search servers and 2 database servers.

I have successfully configured, failover cluster and high availability in the database servers.

While configuring SharePoint 2019 with the configuration wizard i have provided listener server name to create the Database, SharePoint configuration wizard is failing to create the Sharepoint_config database.

I am getting below error in the logs "Login failed for user 'xxx\farm'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config" requested by the login. The login failed.

xxx\farm accout has sys admin,security admin, server admin and DB Creator roles in both the database servers. Still i am not able to create the database.

In the event viewer i am getting below error

SQL Database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance 'xxx-xx-SPHL01'(listener name) not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'xxx\farm'

Comment: Can you login to the database using SQL Server Managament Studio using your farm account?

Comment: yes i am able to login to the database with the account

Comment: we have Resolved the issue, In Azure load balancer floating Ip is disabled. After enabling floating ip Sharepoint_config ran successfully